# How to display cell values only if they are highlighted?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Basically what I want to do is to display values in specific column only if the row(B5) is highlighted(Hereinafter column E) . And if it is highlighted then multiply column C by D.

Could anyone please help me out? Thanks

Comment: Add a formula to column E to do the multiplication for each of the rows and then use the AutoFilter to filter by color.  The extra formulas in the non-highlighted rows will not be visible once filtered.  See here for the filter: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/18/sort-by-color-excel/#filter-cells-color.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say whether or not you can use macros.  If you can, this is what I'd use:

```
Option Explicit

Dim TCol As Integer

Dim TRow As Integer

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  If TCol = 5 Then Range("E" & TRow).Value = ""

  TCol = Target.Column
  TRow = Target.Row

  If TCol = 5 Then Range("E" & TRow).Value = Range("C" & TRow).Value * Range("D" & TRow).Value

End Sub
```

The *TCol* and *TRow* variables must remain outside the SheetSelectionChange (under Option Explicit) so they remain active and aren't redeclared to 0 each time a new cell is clicked.